# Not able to setup vscode.dev to run Python or Jupyter in browser (without downloading or installing)

Tags: python, github, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I am trying to use online browser based version of visual studio code (https://vscode.dev). I installed the extension Python and Jupyter. But when I try to run any code, I get following error.

"Error loading webview: Error: Could not register service workers: NotSupportedError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope".

Looking for your kind help please.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide your operating system? Do you have Python installed on your machine?

Comment: How are you running the code?

Comment: Thanks, this is not an installed one and doesn't depend on the OS. This is directly on the browser (https://vscode.dev/). No install required.

Comment: ack I forgot! Sorry-

Answer (score 0):

Fast soluton: Open the terminal and type `killall code`. Easy & lazy solution: Reboot your computer.

If this does not work, try reinstalling or updating vscode

Comment: Thanks, this is not an installed one. This is directly on the browser (https://vscode.dev/). No install required.

Comment: @ClinicalInfo I'm sorry for neglecting this point. Running code is currently impossible on the vscode web page. Since VS Code for the Web runs completely within the browser, some experiences will naturally be more constrained when compared to what you can do in the desktop app. For example, the terminal and debugger are not available, which makes sense since you can't compile, run, and debug a Rust or Go application within the browser sandbox.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/vscode-web#_limitations

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was related to a CORS configuration issue. What fixed it for me was launching the notebook from the terminal with the origin specified:

`jupyter notebook --no-browser --NotebookApp.allow_origin_pat=https://.*vscode-cdn\.net`

If for some reason that doesn't work, you could try the following as a last resort (bearing in mind this will allow ANY origin):

`jupyter notebook --no-browser --NotebookApp.allow_origin='*'`

Source:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/wiki/Connecting-to-a-remote-Jupyter-server-from-vscode.dev

Comment: Will this work for the web version of vscode?

Comment: Yes, it did for me.